# Add new Js,css files in joomla component

Tags: php, file, joomla, insert, components

I want to insert .js files & css files into my joomla component,and call all these files in a .php file.Is anybody know whats the procedure for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Happen to be working on this right now.
In file `\com_yourcomponent\views\yourview\view.html.php`, within function `display()`,

```
$document->addStyleSheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
$document->addCustomTag('<script type="text/javascript" src="components/com_yourcomponent/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

in your components use :

```
    $js = JUri::root() . 'mycssFolder/style.css';
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScript($js);
```

for more info http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScript

Comment: this helped me out a lot. though should be `$doc->addStyleSheet($js);` for adding a stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla! 2.5, I used the following code in the view display() :

```
JHtml::stylesheet(JURI::base() . 'components/com_mycomponent/css/mycomponent.css', array(), true);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best place to ask:
http://forum.joomla.org/

Ok, ok, for the downvoters: stackoverflow.com  :)